# Switch Vcc to Ground with a control bit

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, switches, cmos

I have a device that is 1 ohm and it consumes 3Amp. I want to run my device in both ways and I have only one voltage supply. I want to switch ground to Vcc and vice versa with a control bit from mcu. I considered cmos invertes, but I am not sure if the resistance of cmos inverter gate is high or not. Because voltage supply can supply limited current. And is it possible to use only 1 control bit to handle this situation, or 2 control bits are needed?

Comment: You can do this with a FET H-bridge, but at 3V that is not easy. Did you consider using a relay?

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen , I do not prefer relay, because of size. I'am searching FET H-bridge now, but why 3V is not easy. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: How much volt drop at 3A are you able to tolerate in the "switches"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, CMOS inverters won't be able to source 3A. As Wouter van Oeijen stated, an H-Bridge is what you want. The princicple of operation is shown below. As shown, S_B1 and S_B2 are closed, causing a current flow from right to left. When you instead close the A-Switches, the current is reversed. When you want no current at all, open all switches. In reallity, the switches will of course be transistors requiring a decent driver stage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fstbK0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A problem with these bridges is, that you must not close i.e. A1 and B1 at the same time. Therefore a certain delay has to added when reversing the current.

What exactly is your load, are you sure that you can assume an ohmic load? Or is it a motor?